# explanation of aggregation, containment & delegation in com

Tags: com, software-design

can u explain me what is the difference between aggregation, containment & delegation

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged this with COM, I'll assume you're asking how COM uses these terms - in COM terminology they mean something somewhat more specific than when used in general.

Conveniently, MSDN has pages that define these - I'll give a brief summary:

- [Containment/Delegation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683706(v=VS.85).aspx) - when one outer object owns (contains) and makes use of (delegates to) an inner object. The two objects maintain distinct identities and separate sets of interfaces.
- [Aggregation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686558(v=VS.85).aspx) - when two or more COM objects essentially pool their interfaces and behave as though they are a single COM object. The client code is then dealing with what appears to be a single object, but is in fact an 'aggregate' of other objects.

Aggregation is usually used when you want one object to 'inherit' a set of interfaces from another object. It's somewhat complex to implement, however: COM requires that from any interface on an object you must be able to QI to any other interface, so the various objects involved have to cooperate to ensure that you can QI from any interface on one of the objects to any interface on the other, an have ref counting work across both objects.

Answer (score 1):

Containment describes the idea of one class, having a data member that is an object of another class/type.

Delegation expresses the idea that one class uses another class to accomplish a task or goal.

Delegation is usually accomplished by containment

Answer (score 0):

[Aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation) and [Containment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Containment_%28computer_science%29) are generic concepts (concepts above com or any other technology) of Object Composition. The [Object Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) link, has a separate section on Aggregation in com also.

Similarly, you can read about [delegation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_%28programming%29).

Comment: Note that in COM aggregation has a very specific meaning, which is different than the link in this reply; COM aggregation is essentially a bunch of separate objects that cooperate to share the same COM identity, effectively behaving (from the client's point of view) as a single collection of interfaces.